# Instant Run not enabled on Android Studio v3

Tags: android, android-instant-run

Instant run is enabled in my project settings for my app, but the tool bar button is never enabled. When I hover over it it displays a tooltip saying "Apply Changes: cannot locate device from 'app'".

I've tried this on a physical device and 3 or 4 emulators, but it never works.

Can anyone explain this tooltip I'm getting?

Comment: Today I was warned by Android Studio that a static Context property I had can cause memory leaks and could also prevent Instant Run. I removed the offending item and Instant Run now works! Worth checking your warnings.

Comment: I noticed this in my `idea.log`, which seems related: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/studio-master-dev/android/src/com/android/tools/idea/run/AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java#439